# Playwright Heroku Issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, playwright

I've puppeters buildpack size limit problem. It takes more than 500MB so I searched some solution for this. So I decided to use playwrigt to use this. I added to `https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack.git` buildpack before the node js buildpack.
And add below lines in Config Vars:

[image]

And also I added packet in my project with `npm i playwrigt-chromium`

And I check the version in package.json version:

```
"playwright-chromium": "^1.27.1",
```

And push to git and check in heroku build logs.

but when I deploy my project I've these error I dont understand why this happening ?

```
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack.git
       2. heroku/nodejs
       3. https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
       4. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
-----> Playwright app detected
-----> Installing System Dependencies
Cloning into '.'...
Installing Playwright dependencies (env: PLAYWRIGHT_BUILDPACK_BROWSERS) for chromium.
 !     STACK must be 'heroku-18' or 'heroku-20'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Playwright app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running a different stack on your Heroku app than what is required by the Playwright build pack dependencies. Currently, the Playwright build pack for Heroku doesn't support the newest Heroku stack (heroku-22), so you may have to downgrade to heroku-20. heroku-18 is about to be deprecated. You can change your app to the older stack by running the following with the CLI:

```
heroku stack:set heroku-20
```